# how to center nav menu on Wordpress for this particular theme

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, center

I'm using Hemingway theme and tying so hard to make center the menu I have spent 5 hours tying to do this so can anyone please tell me how to do it.

fancyentrepreneur.com

ok the navbar css

```
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*  4. Navigation
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


.mobile-menu { display: none; }

.blog-menu li { position: relative; }
.blog-menu > li { float: left; }

.blog-menu > li:before {
    content: "/";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -9px;
    margin-left: -3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #444;
    font-weight: 300;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.blog-menu > li:first-child:before { content: none; }

.blog-menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 27px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    font-size: 13px;
}

.blog-menu a:hover,
.blog-menu .current-menu-item a { color: #FFF; }

.blog-menu > .has-children a,
.blog-menu > .page_item_has_children a { padding-right: 35px; }

.blog-menu > .has-children::after,
.blog-menu > .page_item_has_children::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1001;
    right: 17px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -2px;
}

.blog-menu > .has-children:hover::after,
.blog-menu > .page_item_has_children:hover::after { border-top-color: #FFF; }

.blog-menu li:hover a {
    background-color: #1D1D1D;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.blog-menu li:hover > a { color: #FFF; }


/* Sub menus --------------------------------------- */


.blog-menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}

.blog-menu ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
}

.blog-menu ul > .has-children::after,
.blog-menu ul > .page_item_has_children::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1001;
    right: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.blog-menu ul > .has-children:hover::after,
.blog-menu ul > .page_item_has_children:hover::after { border-right-color: #FFF; }

.blog-menu ul li {  
    width: 240px; 
    background: #1d1d1d;
}

.blog-menu ul a {
    padding: 20px 0px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    line-height: 130%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

.blog-menu ul > li:last-child a { border-bottom-width: 0; }

.blog-menu li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}


/* Deep down --------------------------------------- */


.blog-menu ul li:hover > ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 240px;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

I am trying to tell you anything that can help so, I have copied the whole navigation code in my editor

Answer (score 0):

try this, add css

```
.blog-menu{text-align: center;}
```

change  `.blog-menu > li` like below

```
.blog-menu > li {
float: none;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
```